# How change notification's sound from list of tunes?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfilemanager, uilocalnotification

[image]

I am making an application in which i have settings window on which shown in image. When i click on ringtone then open a list of ringtones which i share by itunes file by using this code

```
- (void)loadSongsFromDocuments {

[listofsongs removeAllObjects];
if(listofsongs==nil)
    listofsongs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documents = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fullExtension = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".wav"];


for (NSString *fileName in [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documents error:nil ] ) {



    if ([fileName rangeOfString:fullExtension].location != NSNotFound) {


        [listofsongs addObject:fileName];

    }

}


NSLog(@"Songs :%@",listofsongs);
```

}

now i want that when i select any row of table view then that tone will set for my local notification's sound. How can i do that?

Thanks in advances...

Comment: Hey, if you take a screenshot, press cmd+shift+4, and then hit <space>, it will allow you to take a screenshot from one screen only. (e.g. the simulator alone without desktop. ;)